Is there an option in QGIS layout to go back to the previous zoom?
QGIS newbie here...
In the layout window, I cannot find a button or keystroke combo to go backward or forward in zoom choices. I would expect this to be a basic option to be found in the layout navigation toolbar, analogous to what one finds in the layout toolbar of ArcMap, or to hitting Alt + → or Alt + ← on the keyboard to zoom a page in a pdf reader.
Would anyone know if this functionality exists or can be implemented?
What I'm looking for would be the equivalent of the zoom last and zoom next buttons found in the map navigation toolbar of the main map window, but for the layout, not the map extent.

Currently there is no interface button or hotkey to rescale the layout to the previous view. You can check this in the layout settings: Settings -> Keyborad Shortcuts
You can create a request for this function here or implement it yourself using pyqgis.

